# c# using "@" for slash delimiter

Tags: c#

I am using \ in a to get the file path as such

```
    string driveLetter = "C:\\";
    string folderName = "324Files";
    string fileName = "rpt3434.txt";
    string stringPath = driveLetter + "MainFolder\\Report" + folderName + "\\" + fileName;
```

I want to use the @ instead but am finding that it is more cumbersome:

```
    string driveLetter = @"C:\";
    string folderName = "324Files";
    string fileName = "rpt3434.txt";
    string stringPath = driveLetter + @"MainFolder\Report" + FolderName + @"\" + fileName;
```

I am wondering which one is the preferred way of doing it?

Comment: "Which is preferred"? With respect to what? Constructing paths? appending strings generally?

Comment: The one that is preferred is the one you prefer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method is here to solve these difficulties.

```
string driveLetter = "C:\\";
string folderName = "324Files";
string fileName = "rpt3434.txt";
string stringPath = Path.Combine(driveLetter,"MainFolder", "Report", folderName, fileName);
Console.WriteLine(stringPath);

C:\MainFolder\Report\324Files\rpt3434.txt
```

or (if you really want to concat "Report" with foldername

```
string stringPath = Path.Combine(driveLetter,"MainFolder", "Report" + folderName, fileName);

C:\MainFolder\Report324Files\rpt3434.txt
```

need to add

```
using System.IO;
```

[Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) contains numerous methods that are very useful when working with strings used to represent files and paths. Also the class is capable to differentiate the syntax used by different underlying operating systems. Thus is really preferable, if you ever plan to port your code to a different platform, whilst an hardcoded backslash will be in need of a fix.

Comment: I don't think this is the same as what the OP has - not far off, but `Report\324Files` should be `Report324Files`.

Comment: Probably you are right, but could also be a typo. Let's the OP explain and then I'll fix the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
string stringPath = string.Format(@"{0}MainFolder\Report{1}\{2}", driveLetter, folderName, fileName);
```

Comment: I added the foldername as in the OP string. I hope you don't mind